# Getting ffmpeg to work on a nodejs server: Error: ffmpeg exited with code 1: Output #0, wav, to 'output.wav'

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, fluent-ffmpeg

I need to convert an m4a buffer stream to a wav buffer stream. I'm trying to accomplish this through ffmpeg-static and fluent-ffmpeg on a nodejs backend. I'm using multer to process the buffer stream coming from the client, then pass it through a *convertM4AToWAV*, which

Here is the code I'm using to establish ffmpeg and convert the buffer stream.

```
const ffmpeg = require('fluent-ffmpeg');
const ffmpegStatic = require('ffmpeg-static');
ffmpeg.setFfmpegPath(ffmpegStatic);

...more code here for the api route...

const convertM4AToWAV = async (m4aBuffer) => {
  console.log(`buffer in: ${m4aBuffer}`);
  try {
    const wavBuffer = await ffmpeg(m4aBuffer)
      .toFormat('wav')
      .on('start', (command) => console.log('FFmpeg command:', command))
      .on('end', () => {
        console.log('Conversion complete.');
      })
      .save('output.wav');
    return wavBuffer;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error converting audio buffer stream to wav:', error);
    throw error;
  }
};
```

And here is the error message I'm seeing:

```
//I can see the buffer come in
buffer in: ↑ftyp3gp4isom3gp4☺mdat????????.....
//I can see the command
FFmpeg command: ffmpeg -y -f wav output.wav
//Error message thrown
Error transcribing audio: Error: 13 INTERNAL: Request message serialization failure: invalid encoding
    at callErrorFromStatus
...file directory jibberish...
code: 13,
  details: 'Request message serialization failure: invalid encoding',
  metadata: Metadata { internalRepr: Map(0) {}, options: {} },
  note: 'Exception occurred in retry method that was not classified as transient'
}
error - uncaughtException: Error: ffmpeg exited with code 1: Output #0, wav, to 'output.wav':
Output file #0 does not contain any stream
```

Any thoughts why this error is thrown? My gut is telling me it's because I haven't configured ffmpeg correctly on the server.